# Editing output behaviorspace

Tags: netlogo, behaviorspace

I'm using behaviorspace of netlogo.

I now have a list with items such as: [8.916710216805878 9] [10.458910216805876 20]

I would like to change the output to: [8.916710216805878; 9]; [10.458910216805876; 20]

I want this so I can read it more easily to analyse it.

Comment: BehaviorSpace has a very specific format - a csv file with the input and output variables as columns. It may be easier to change the produced file using regular expressions or similar. Alternatively, you could include some code in your model that writes to a file.